# Make Alt+Enter Send the End key, modifiers not working?

Tags: autohotkey

Pretty simple question, but I'm having issues. I tried this `!Enter::Send, {End}` It works great, but the problem I'm having is that I can't use other modifiers with it. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> should act as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> should behave as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>

I tried this too `*!Enter::Send, {End}` but it seems to ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and or <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hotkeys consume their events so the `*` is eating the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> events.

`*` is useful when you want a range of hotkeys to all do the same thing.

```
*#c::Run Calc.exe  ; Win+C, Shift+Win+C, Ctrl+Win+C, etc. all launch calc
```

The following should do what you want.

```
!Enter::^End
```

or

```
!Enter:: Send, {End}
+!Enter:: Send, +{End}
^!Enter:: Send, ^{End}
```

Comment: It's kind of lame that you have to map each modifier explicitly. Works great though

Comment: It seems to work as a hotstring; so you don't.
`!Enter::^End`